# Conitue ssh from previous state

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm accessing through ssh to a linux box. I was simply updateing the packages with `yum update`. I then disconnected but when I connnected again with ssh using the same account I couldn't now if the update process had already finished.

How can I know the status of tasks I've started before disconnecting when I reconnect to the server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`screen <program>`](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/cd/soft/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html). At this point you can either disconnect or hit CTRL-A, CTRL-D and do other things. You can later re-attach your session to the screen running your program by `screen -r`.

Specifically if you want to save the state of your shell between ssh sessions you can just run `screen` and then run your programs.

Comment: [dtach](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/) is quite a lot simpler than screen.  I like screen though, I use it for full sessions (not just one command).